# Load a jar in Java Class

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have a simple java class I want to load a jar file in my main method. How can I load the jar so that its available

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, IOException{

    String connectionString = "connectionstring";
    File platformDB = new File(tempDir, "PlatformDB.eap");

    createNewTempDirectory();
    Mirror  m = new Mirror(connectionString, createEmptyEap(emptyEapName) ,platformDB.getAbsolutePath());
    m.run();
}
```

Mirror Class

```
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
}
```

In Mirror.run method I try to make a connection to database

Mirror.run() method

```
 public void run() {
    this.source = DriverManager.getConnection(EaDbStringParser.eaDbStringToJdbc(sourceString));
    this.source.setReadOnly(true);
}
```

I have a jar file located under "C:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" 
How can I load this jar so the connection is made successfully

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about setting the correct classpath.  Are you using an IDE?  Are you using any build tool (eg Maven)?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run the class with the `-classpath` option:

```
java -classpath C:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar
```

Comment: where should I specify -classpath?

Comment: I am running it from eclipse

Comment: @wearybands Either add the JAR as a dependency (right click project > Build Path > Add External Archives) or add it to the run configuration (right click main method > Run As > Run Configurations > select relevant run configuration or create a new one > Classpath tab).

Comment: Yes I added in the classpath as external jar but I get the following error now  WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: I think I need to add this dll somewhere but I dont know where

Comment: I added -Djava.library.path=C:/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/auth/x86 under VM arguments in my run configuration and added System.loadLibrary("sqljdbc_auth"); before calling DriverManager.getConnection still getting the error

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct version for your OS, 32 or 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add the jar to the classpath loading the main class. For example if Mirror is the class with the main method where you say from console

```
`java Mirror'
```

modify it to

```
'java -cp C:/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar Mirror`
```